# Erro na reprodução do áudio no streaming de video

Tags: objective-c, swift, mobile, streaming

Estou tentando reproduzir um **streaming de video** mas está dando **problemas no áudio**. Na plataforma Android, consegui reproduzi-lo sem erros e na web também está em uma qualidade boa.

Ja peguei vários exemplos de projetos que reproduzem streaming na internet, mas todos apresentam o mesmo erro no áudio quando coloco o link que estou usando.

Por funcionar em outras plataformas, acredito que deve ser algum problema com o IOS em especifico. Sua extensão é **.m3u8**.

## Estou fazendo desta forma: (Swift)

(Link mencionado no código é o link que esta dando problemas apenas no ios) - Caso saibam alguma solução, pode ser tanto em Swift ou objective-C.

**link streaming -** http://d1t4ozb7rtitmv.cloudfront.net/acustica/myStream/playlist.m3u8

**link web -** http://www.acusticafm.com.br/video.php

```
import UIKit


let videoUrl = NSURL(string: "http://d1t4ozb7rtitmv.cloudfront.net/acustica/myStream/playlist.m3u8")!

class ViewControllerV: UIViewController, PlayerDelegate {

    private var player: Player!
    @IBOutlet var viewV: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var viewK: UIView!


    // MARK: object lifecycle

    convenience init() {
        self.init(nibName: nil, bundle:nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    // MARK: view lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        //TELA . . .
        let mode = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
        UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(mode, forKey: "orientation")
      

        self.view.autoresizingMask = ([UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight])

        self.player = Player()
        self.player.delegate = self
        self.player.view.frame = self.view.bounds
    

        self.viewV.addSubview(self.player.view) 
        self.player.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    
        self.player.setUrl(videoUrl)
    
        self.player.playbackLoops = true
    
        let tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTapGestureRecognizer:")
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.player.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    }



    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
        self.player.playFromBeginning()

    }

    // MARK: UIGestureRecognizer

    func handleTapGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        switch (self.player.playbackState.rawValue) {
            case PlaybackState.Stopped.rawValue:
                self.player.playFromBeginning()
            case PlaybackState.Paused.rawValue:
                self.player.playFromCurrentTime()
            case PlaybackState.Playing.rawValue:
                self.player.pause()
            case PlaybackState.Failed.rawValue:
                self.player.pause()
            default:
                self.player.pause()
         }
    }

    // MARK: PlayerDelegate

    func playerReady(player: Player) {
    }

    func playerPlaybackStateDidChange(player: Player) {
    }

    func playerBufferingStateDidChange(player: Player) {
    }

    func playerPlaybackWillStartFromBeginning(player: Player) {
    }

    func playerPlaybackDidEnd(player: Player) {
    }


    //TELA
    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

}
```

Vi agora, se eu abrir pelo **safari** ou outro navegador qualquer no meu **iphone** o link da versão do streaming web, da o mesmo erro mas, se eu abrir pelo meu computador funciona normalmente.

Comment: Aqui o link não funcionou em nenhum navegador.

Comment: Opa, realmente, ele não funciona 24 hrs, geralmente funciona pela parte da manha/tarde, pelas 11:00, 12:00 hrs

Comment: Amanhã nesse horário eu testo ele no Swift e vejo o que é